# How to convert fetch request for graphql query with mutation?

Tags: graphql, fetch

So I got this fetch request from browser console

```
fetch("redacted", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,ml;q=0.8",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Chromium\";v=\"88\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"88\", \";Not A Brand\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "x-access-token": "redacted",
    "x-language": "en",
    "x-lockdown-token": "undefined"
  },
  "referrer": "redacted",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "{\"operationName\":\"DiceRoll\",\"variables\":{\"target\":50.5,\"condition\":\"above\",\"identifier\":\"9a268cd34509814f4d2e\",\"amount\":1e-8,\"currency\":\"doge\"},\"query\":\"mutation DiceRoll($amount: Float!, $target: Float!, $condition: CasinoGameDiceConditionEnum!, $currency: CurrencyEnum!, $identifier: String!) {\\n  diceRoll(amount: $amount, target: $target, condition: $condition, currency: $currency, identifier: $identifier) {\\n    ...CasinoBetFragment\\n    state {\\n      ...DiceStateFragment\\n      __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment CasinoBetFragment on CasinoBet {\\n  id\\n  active\\n  payoutMultiplier\\n  amountMultiplier\\n  amount\\n  payout\\n  updatedAt\\n  currency\\n  game\\n  user {\\n    id\\n    name\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment DiceStateFragment on CasinoGameDice {\\n  result\\n  target\\n  condition\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\"}",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

I want to make this request in a javascript. So far I've got

```
fetch("redacted", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-access-token": "redacted",
  },
  "body": JSON.stringify({
        operationName:"DiceRoll",
        variables:{
            target:50.5,
            condition:"above",
            identifier:"5997586b28731dbdcd53",
            amount:1e-8,
            currency:"doge"
            },
        query:` mutation DiceRoll($amount: Float!, $target: Float!, $condition:CasinoGameDiceConditionEnum!, $currency: CurrencyEnum!, $identifier: String!) {\\ndiceRoll(amount: $amount, target: $target, condition: $condition, currency: $currency, identifier:$identifier) {\\n    ...CasinoBetFragment\\n    state {\\n      ...DiceStateFragment\\n __typename\\n    }\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n}\\n\\nfragment CasinoBetFragment on CasinoBet {\\n  id\\nactive\\n  payoutMultiplier\\n  amountMultiplier\\n  amount\\n  payout\\n  updatedAt\\n  currency\\ngame\\n  user {\\n    id\\n    name\\n    __typename\\n  }\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\\nfragment DiceStateFragment on CasinoGameDice {\\n  result\\n  target\\n  condition\\n  __typename\\n}\\n\}`
})
});
```

But its throwing an error

unknown query "mutationDiceRoll" (548654)","errorType":"graphqlError"

How do I send mutated query using fetch. Or if possible, can I do this on jQuery?

Comment: test in playground first (using variables, of course) ... if works code to have the same network request shape/body ... use search

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url:weburl,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "x-access-token": token
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'operationName':"DiceRoll",
                'variables':{
                    'target':chance,
                    'condition':direction,
                    'identifier':Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10),
                    'amount':bet,
                    'currency':coin
                },
            'query': 'mutation DiceRoll($amount: Float!, $target: Float!, $condition: CasinoGameDiceConditionEnum!, $currency: CurrencyEnum!, $identifier: String!) {\x0a  diceRoll(amount: $amount, target: $target, condition: $condition, currency: $currency, identifier: $identifier) {\x0a    ...CasinoBetFragment\x0a    state {\x0a      ...DiceStateFragment\x0a      __typename\x0a    }\x0a    __typename\x0a  }\x0a}\x0a\x0afragment CasinoBetFragment on CasinoBet {\x0a  id\x0a  active\x0a  payoutMultiplier\x0a  amountMultiplier\x0a  amount\x0a  payout\x0a  updatedAt\x0a  currency\x0a  game\x0a  user {\x0a    id\x0a    name\x0a    __typename\x0a  }\x0a  __typename\x0a}\x0a\x0afragment DiceStateFragment on CasinoGameDice {\x0a  result\x0a  target\x0a  condition\x0a  __typename\x0a}\x0a'    
            }),
            success: function(data) {}})
```